# QGIS cannot open layer properties and crashes

Tags: qgis

I have loaded raster and trying see the properties from the layer explorer it is crashing (qgis-2.18.20). I have deleted .qgis2 folder as well

Comment: What is your OS? Do you try latest **QGIS 2.18.22**? Do you try alternative builds like [NextGIS QGIS 18.7.2](http://nextgis.com/nextgis-qgis/)?

Comment: Hi I am using Windows 7 OS

Comment: Actually I have compiled the source code and running on window7 OS I tried using the installer provided in the QGIS download link but it is crashing

Comment: Do you try NextGIS installer? It's installed QGIS separately and not influence on any other QGIS in your system?

Comment: Hello tried in Next GIS it is working,So what could be the possible problem it is crashing in the QGIS 2.18.22 version

Comment: A lot of cases may lead to crash: old dependency library versions, old compiler version, your system dependencies, etc.

Comment: I tried to compile NextGIS and I have qt5.11 version but when trying to do cmake but it is showing support for qt4 could you please help me

Comment: QGIS 2.x required Qt4 (mainly for PyQt4 needed for plugins support). The Qt5 is required for QGIS 3.x. You mast decide QGIS 2 and Qt4 or QGIS 3 and Qt5.